# Prestashop 1.5 how to save custom form using hook while processing order address form

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have added custom form on order address form.

While saving order address I want to save custom form also, but it saves order address only.

Can anyone help me please?

[image: Custom form Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I've done this on my project. It's not a clean option but it's working as expecting.

At the top of `order-carrier.tpl` I've added a hook:

```
{hook h="checkCustomForm"}
```

I've created a module `/mdoules/customform/customform.php`

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class CustomForm extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'customform';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Florian Lemaitre';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Custom Form');
        $this->description = $this->l('Custom Form');
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return $this->createTable()
            && parent::install()
            && $this->registerHook('checkCustomForm');
    }

    public function hookcheckCustomForm($params)
    {

        [process your form values here (Tools::getValue('my_value') ...)]

        if (error)
        {
            // We redirect to the Adrress page with a flag 'missing_value' to alert an error
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1&missing_value=true');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use redirect, errors in context are gone. Moreover my form is not prefilled with new values. How to maintain error and data from request using redirects. Or is there any other way to do so?